# How can i copy a table into another table in laravel

Tags: laravel

Right now I have 2 tables with exact same data. Every 5 min I run a `updateorcreate` to update the table 2 fields with new data from table 1. The problem I face is that if I delete something from table 1 then it wont delete it from table 2 after i run `updateorcreate` which is expected. Does Laravel have a way to do this without `truncate()`?

Comment: Why use two table with same data ?

Comment: @Saromase 1 is local and another one is remote. I run a lot of queries and having it remote slows the process.